# Does AWS Sagemaker charge for S3 streamed data in PIPE mode (for model training)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

On the AWS developer docs for Sagemaker, they recommend us to use PIPE mode to directly stream large datasets from S3 to the model training containers (since it's faster, uses less disk storage, reduces training time, etc.).

However, they don't include information on whether this data streaming transfer is charged for (they only include data transfer pricing for their model building & deployment stages, not training).

So, I wanted to ask if anyone knew whether this data transfer in PIPE mode is charged for, since if it is, I don't get how this would be recommended for large datasets, since streaming a few epochs for each model iteration can get prohibitively expensive for large datasets (my dataset, for example, is 6.3TB on S3).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are charged for the S3 GET calls that you do similarly to what you would be charged if you used the FILE option of the training. However, these charges are usually marginal compared to the alternatives.

When you are using the FILE mode, you need to pay for the local EBS on the instances, and for the extra time that your instances are up and only copying the data from S3. If you are running multiple epochs, you will not benefit much from the PIPE mode, however, when you have so much data (6.3 TB), you don't really need to run multiple epochs.

The best usage of PIPE mode is when you can use a **single pass** over the data. In the era of big data, this is a better model of operation, as you can't retrain your models often. In SageMaker, you can point to your "old" model in the "model" channel, and your "new" data in the "train" channel and benefit from the PIPE mode to the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that on S3's official pricing page, it says the following under the **Data transfer** section:

> Transfers between S3 buckets or from Amazon S3 to any service(s) within the same AWS Region are free.

And since my S3 bucket and my Sagemaker instances will be in the same AWS region, the data transfer costs should be free.

Comment: You'll be charged for S3 GET requests, but not for data transfer. The price will depend on how many objects you'll be reading from S3. See Guy's answer.